# Sorting bar chart based on Set In-Out values

Tags: tableau-api

I want to sort bar charts based on Set In-Out values. Like In values should come first and then out values.

Example: I have created a set for top 10 countries based on sales%. So in the chart top 10 countries in the set should come first (set IN values) then other countries (set OUT values) should come after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Set to your Viz as the left-most dimension.  It will have the In/Out values.  You can then sort it like any other dimension if it doesn't come in the right order.